# YYYYwwe parsed not as expected

Tags: java, scala, datetime

I created a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` like this:

```
val customFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear(), 4)
        .appendValue(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 2)
        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
        .toFormatter()
```

To parse the week of the following strings `2013014` `2015233` `2020117` I'm using:

```
val weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault())
LocalDate.parse(dateString, customFormatter).get(weekFields.weekBasedYear())
```

The results are like this:

```
+-------+----+----+---+
|partcol|year|week|day|
+-------+----+----+---+
|2013014|2013|   1|  4|
|2015233|2015|  23|  3|
|2020117|2020|  12|  7|
+-------+----+----+---+
```

The week of `2020` will be always +1 above the desired. In this scenario I'm trying to parse the time info to get `weekBasedYear`, `weekOfWeekBasedYear` and `DAY_OF_WEEK`.

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.232.09.1 (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.232.09.1 (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and actually ask a question. As it is now I can't determine what you're actually asking for and whether the results you show are what you expect or what you get and whether you'd consider them to be correct or not.

Comment: `weekBasedYear` and `weekOfWeekBasedYear` are different fields for a reason: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Week schemes differ (that’s the whole reason for having a `WeekFields` class). You are using `WeekFields.ISO` for parsing and then `WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault())` for printing the individual fields back. That’s gotta give different results sometimes.

According to ISO the first week of the year is the first week that contains at least 4 days of the new year. I can reproduce your week of 12 (+1 compared to the parsed week 11) in locales where week 1 is the week containing January 1. This is the case for example in some Arabic locales (where the week begins on Saturday) and in Israel (where the week begins on Sunday).

I believe that the solution is simple: use the same `WeekFields` object for parsing and for printing (or equivalent `WeekFields` objects).

Answer (score 0):

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
        .appendValue(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, 2)
        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
        .toFormatter()
```

`LocalDate.parse(dateString, customFormatter).get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK)`